# powerbi not refreshing in time

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I am having the same issues with powerBI ,seems the automatic refresh its failing ,i currently have to click refresh to see new data coming in ,i have configure the the tumblingwindow part e.g **tumblingwindow(second,3)**,done the live to dashboard are the any other settings/factors i have to set for the automatic refresh to work.(its a console app that selects data from database and sends each row to event hubs from event hubs to stream analytics then output is powerBi ).i am assuming the is time restrictions depending on throughput but how do i really calculate the time for tumblingwindow i should set ,i have tried the equation **entitycount*60*60/throughput = seconds** still no success.

below is a code but still the events take time to reach powerBi even after **tumblingwindow(second,3)** ,i could stop my application running then delete the dataset from powerbi ,but then the dataset will reappear

**EventData data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedobjects));
 eventHubClient.SendAsync(data);**

Comment: Are you looking at dashboard tiles and they aren't refreshing? Or are you looking at the reports behind the tiles and they aren't refreshing?

Comment: Hi thanks for the responds ,i have done everything on the list and the are no issues ,everything seems to be working fine so to archive partially what i wanted i used Q and A

Answer (score 0):

Overall workflow you describe seems fine and tumbling window size should not cause the data to never show up. You will have to debug this issue, with following steps

- Goto Azure portal, inputs page for the stream analytics job and get a "sample". Does it return you any samples?
- Goto Monitoring page in azure portal and check if  input events and output events are greater than zero. If you see input events but don't see output events, you are likely hitting an error writing to output.
- Also check if operation logs has any errors for this job.

Above steps should tell you if something is wrong with event format or the output.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responds ,i have done everything on the list and the are no issues ,everything seems to be working fine so to archive partially what i wanted i used Q and A.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pinning the individual live tile to the dashboard or the entire report? Pinning the entire report does not appear to work.

If you pin the single tile containing the data you want, does that refresh in real time?